# VueJS How to filter array data when using dropdown select

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `vue`-app I have an array of job-postings, which have different states, such as "active", "rejected", "draft", "not_active" etc. Now I have a TabMenu: All Jobs, Drafts and To Be Approved. Each of those MenuTabs, have their own Dropdown menu, where you are supposed to filter the jobpostings. I've realized that this feature is more complex than expected, or maybe I have spend too much time with the issues, but for some reason, I cannot manage, to show "all" for the individual MenuTab. For example, when I click on the "To Be Approved" MenuTab, I want to see all the jobpostings, with the status "Not approved" and "Rejected" (See data below in the code).

So my question is, how to solve this properly? Does the job-posting data object need to have a category too?

Any help is most welcome!

So, here is my component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(tab, index) in menuTabs” :key="tab.id" :class="{ 'active': activeTab === index  }"
        @click="toggleList(tab, index)” >
         <span>{{tab.label}}</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="dropdown has-prepend col-8" :class="{ active: isOpen }">
     <div :class="{ active: isOpen }" class="dropdown-select" @click="toggle">
        {{ selectedOption }}
       <i class="icon-chevron_down" />
     </div>
     <div class="dropdown-options" v-show="isOpen">
       <div class="option" v-for="tab in dropDownTabs" @click="select(tab)" :key="tab.id">
         <span>{{ tab.status }}</span>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <DataTable :data="filteredData" :columns="tableColumns" :filter="search" />
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

import DataTable from '../../snippets/DataTable';

export default {
  components: { DataTable },
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      search: "",
      tableData: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Salesperson",
        publish_date: "2019-07-10",
        status: "active",
        applicants: 23,
        expiration_date: "2020-02-21"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Developer",
        publish_date: "2019-11-12",
        status: "not_active",
        applicants: 111,
        expiration_date: "2020-02-21"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "Freelanceer",
        publish_date: "2019-06-10",
        status: "need_approval",
        applicants: 222,
        expiration_date: "2020-01-10"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: "Construction worker",
        publish_date: "2019-12-06",
        status: "active",
        applicants: 76,
        expiration_date: "2020-03-15"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: "IT support”
        publish_date: "2019-11-20",
        status: "draft",
        applicants: 103,
        expiration_date: "2020-04-31"
      },
    ],
    menuTabs: [
     {
       label: "All jobs",
       options: [
       {
         status: "all",
       },
       {
        status: "active",
       },
       {
        status: "not_active"
       }
     ]
    },
    {
      label: "Drafts",
      options: [
      {
        status: "all"
      },
      {
        status: "draft"
      }
     ]
   },
   {
     label: "To Be Approved",
     options: [
     {
       status: "all",
     },
     {
       status: "need_approval",
     },
     {
       status: "rejected"
     }
     ]
   },
  ],
  dropDownTabs: [],
  selectedOption: "",
  selectedTabCategory: "",
  category: "",
  activeTab: "",
  tableColumns: [
    "id",
    "title",
    "publish_date",
    "status",
    "applicants",
    "expiration_date"
  ]
 }
},
computed: {
  filteredData() {
    let status = this.selectedOption;

    let category = this.category;

    let filtered = this.tableData.filter(data => {
    if (status == "all") {
      return data;
    }
    return data.status === status;
  });
  return filtered;
 }
},
methods: {
  toggleList(tab, index) {
    this.category = tab.options[0].category;
    this.selectedTabCategory = tab;
    let currentTabOptions = this.selectedTabCategory.options;

    this.clearDropDown();
    this.selectedOption = currentTabOptions[0].status;

    currentTabOptions.forEach(option => {
      this.dropDownTabs.push(option);
    });

    this.activeTab = index;
  },
  toggle() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  },
  select(tab) {
    this.selectedOption = tab.status;

    let category = tab.category;

    let filtered = this.tableData.filter(data => {
      return data.status === this.selectedOption;
    });

    this.isOpen = false;

    return filtered;
  },
  clearDropDown() {
     this.dropDownTabs = [];
  }
},
created() {},
mounted() {
  this.selectedOption = this.menuTabs[0].options[0].status;
  this.selectedTabCategory = this.menuTabs[0].label;
  this.category = this.menuTabs[0].options[0].category;
  let defaultOptions = this.menuTabs[0].options;
  defaultOptions.forEach(option => {
    this.dropDownTabs.push(option);
  });
  this.activeTab = 0;
 }
};
```

Comment: Could you create a quick fiddle for this so that we can verify? Or please make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help you at all. However I will try anyway.

You should store the selected tab when you click on it. Then filter the `this.tableData` based on the selected tab `options`. Also you will need map the tab option `options` to array of strings, so you can check if the posting status is in there.

```js
methods: {
  toggleList (tab, index) {
    this.selectedTabObject = tab
    // rest of your code...
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredData () {
    return this.tableData.filter(data => {
      const states = this.selectedTabObject.options.map(opt => opt.status)
      return states.includes(data.status)
    })
  }
}
```

Also I have created simple fiddle to mimic your problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/3hqnp7u2/7/